# Keydown in Chrome causing weird positioning in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, iframe, keydown

We have a slider that loads slides as iframes, pure html, css and js. Chrome has a weird bug that moves the iframes on key down. Is this a known chrome bug or is it code related? Unfortunately, I cannot provide any source code.

Chrome
[image: chrome]

Firefox
[image]

Comment: Just figured this is only an issue on a Retina display. Chrome version: 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit) (same problem on previous versions too: 73 and v45.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug on Chrome related to handling iframe contents.

It is now seems to be partly fixed with v50.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=597254&q=iframe%20input%20focus&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified